# How can postfix hash: databases be replaced by static: or inline:?

Tags: postfix, database, sql

What is the syntax to replace a postfix hash-Database, for example

```
domain.tld PREPEND my-header: foobar
```

with a static map?

[docs](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html) define it as `Example: "inline:{ key=value, { key = text with whitespace or comma }}"`.

Several ways to replace it seemed not to work and its even unclear, how many fields the hash: db really has. is the domain the only key and the rest a string? Should there be some list-syntax for the three fields associated to the domain? And what about a key with multiple values (multiple lines starting with the same domain in the hash: db)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I'll try to clear some confusions here about postfix lookup table based on [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html). In short, postfix table must be consisted of key-value pair. Both of key-value has string datatype.

> how many fields the hash: db really has. is the domain the only key and the rest a string?

YES. Just ONE key and ONE value. The value has several formats which address different purpose, such as alias, transport, access, etc. See [postfix man pages](http://www.postfix.org/postfix-manuals.html), especially in **Table-driven mechanisms** section.

> Should there be some list-syntax for the three fields associated to the domain?

Some table support that list-like string. For example alias table allows you to define multiple alias target for example.

```
root root@gmail.com root@yahoo.com
```

In here, the value was separated by space or comma.

> And what about a key with multiple values (multiple lines starting with the same domain in the hash: db)?

When table has duplicate key, then postfix will choose the value of the first match. In case of hash table, the top entry was chosen, the others value were ignored.

---

*Now, I'll try to answer your question about static and/or inline maps. Please note that these two table types were different of each other.*

The inline maps will be introduced in postfix version 3.0. Currently there are no postfix stable release that support that table type. You can read it in postfix 3.0 RC1 [release notes](http://de.postfix.org/ftpmirror/official/postfix-3.0.0-RC1.RELEASE_NOTES).

Let say you want to convert hash table with entries like this

```
example.com DEFER come back later please
example.net REJECT
example.org PREPEND X-Foo: Bar
```

Then the equivalent inline maps is

```
inline:{{example.com=DEFER come back later please}, example.net=REJECT, {example.org=PREPEND X-Foo: Bar}}
```

For text without space, we can use key=value syntax. With spaces, you need bracket to surround it.

Now, the static maps was different. The table was like wildcard-key table. Postfix may lookup whatever key, but the answer would be static value. For postfix with version lower 3.0, the static table [doesn't support value string with space](https://web.archive.org/web/20140107233841/http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html). For postfix 3.0 and later, you may wrap the the value with bracket to add spaces in it. For example

```
static:REJECT
```

or

```
static:{REJECT get out from my postfix}
```

Comment: Thank you. Especially the docs about what the tables work like were not that clear to me. And then i guess you need to know, what the queries are (for example in a virtual_alias_maps table). But i want the inline table for some headers only, so it will be fine (if my postfix supports it).